# React environment variable not working in dev

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

Please put me out of my misery.  I see scores of other people had the same issue and I don't see a solution.

I am trying to put my sensitive keys into environment-specific files (.env.development, .env.staging, etc).  The keys work fine if I put them in .env but I need this file for some other items which must be pushed up to source control. All of the files are in root (I see that this was a common mistake).  Is there something with webpack that is the issue?  I have restarted the server instance every time I make a change.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

console.log('ENV', process.env.NODE_ENV);   // this returns "development"
console.log('Hello?', process.env.REACT_APP_HELLO);  // this returns "undefined"
```

As noted I am surfacing the environment correctly.

```
 "start": "SET NODE_ENV=development&& node server/index.js",
```

from package.json

```
REACT_APP_HELLO=BLAH
```

from .env.development

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're in cmd.exe because of the `set`. Add a space before the `&&`: `"start": "set NODE_ENV=development && node server",` (no need to specify `index.js`. On non-Windows systems this would be `NODE_ENV=development node server`.

EDIT:

To get `.env.development` working, change the dotenv line to this: `require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.' + process.env.NODE_ENV })`. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55426597/5774952)), or the `custom-env` package: `require('custom-env').env(process.env.NODE_ENV)`. Neither of those inherit from the regular `.env` though, so if you need that, check out [dotenv-flow](https://github.com/kerimdzhanov/dotenv-flow). I haven't tried the last package, but it seems to have the most features and the least amount of config to get working.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response!  Actually I think you are wrong about the space - I had something fail separately recently because a space was added to the end of the variable.  Anyway, I did try it - same result.  Yes, I am on windows.

Comment: `&&` isn't part of the environment variable, it's an operator. It means "do the thing on the left, and if that doesn't fail, then do the thing on the right." But I see the other problem, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Right - I completely get that.  What I am saying is that I did something similar recently where the resulting variable had a space in it when there was a space before the ampersand.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was exactly the problem!  Incidentally I also tried it with the space before the ampersand - that absolutely broke it.

Comment: Bizarre, that's not what I would expect (but I also don't use Windows hardly ever, so there could be something I'm forgetting). Anyway I'm glad the env problem is sorted out!