# How to avoid getting wrong data from process.env file?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables

I need to get some data from a .env.local file,however instead of getting the data of the file on the current folder i get the one from another project that i had made.
How can I make node recognise the right file to read?
example:

folder-structure:

```
folder:
   file.js
   .env.local
```

js file:

```
   const envData ={
      test1: process.env.TEST_1,
      test2: process.env.TEST_2,
      test3: process.env.TEST_3,
    })
```

.env.local file:

```
TEST_1=test1-data
TEST_2=test2-data
TEST_3=test3-data
```

The problem is:I don't get the data from the env file in my folder but from another one,how do I fix this?

Comment: Why would you use the env variable file from another project?

Comment: How are you loading the env file?

Comment: @mars it's not that i want to use it,it's the program that when i write process.env.NAME_OF_THE_VARIABLE, get's it from another folder containing a .env file instead of the current folder and i don't know why

Comment: @Mureinik i'm not loadining it,i just write process.env.NAME_OF_THE_VARIABLE

Comment: Where in your file structure is the env variable that's being loaded? Are they env variables set up in your Bash profile or something?

Comment: [`dotenv`](https://npmjs.com/package/dotenv) might be a good choice. On the other hand, you can also just change the name of your environment variables so they don't collide. Look at the first answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406055/toggle-between-multiple-env-files-like-env-development-with-node-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toggle between multiple .env files like .env.development with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406055/toggle-between-multiple-env-files-like-env-development-with-node-js)

Comment: @code yeah thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to manage your environment variables -- it loades environment variables from a `.env` file into `process.env`. So you'll have your `.env` file within your project folder and then whichever folder you need to load your env variables in, you'll require and configure the package at the top of the file like so:
`require('dotenv').config();`

Which will allow you to call your env variables like `process.env.XXX`.