# dotenv does not load when path has variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I am trying to use dotenv to manage configurations for different environment. At the moment, I only have development environment. To test dotenv library, I have `.env` and `.env.development` files in the root folder.

In `.env`, I have

```
PORT=5001
```

In `.env.development`, I have

```
PORT=5002
```

In `index.js`, if I have `require('dotenv').config()`, `.env` file is loaded and I can see `process.env.PORT` is 5001.

If I have `require('dotenv').config({path: '.env.'+process.env.NODE_ENV})`, and I also have `NODE_ENV=development node index.js`, then `.env.development` is not loaded.

However, if I have `require('dotenv').config({path: '.env.development'})`, `.env.development` file is loaded correctly.

Can I please get some help? Thank you

**Update**

The test code I am having is

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
console.log(environment);
const dotenvPath = '.env.'+environment;
console.log(dotenvPath);
dotenv.config({path: dotenvPath});

console.log(process.env.PORT);
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

and I am in Windows.

When I run `set NODE_ENV=development &  node index.js`, the console log is

In CMD:

```
D:\>set NODE_ENV=development &  node index.js
development
.env.development
undefined
development
```

In Powershell, it is correct.

```
PS D:\> $env:NODE_ENV='development'; node index.js
development
.env.development
5001
development
```

I guess when I put the command as script in package.json, the command is run in CMD, rather than in Powershell, even though I run `npm run start:development` in Powershell.

Comment: Can you try to console log `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the reason.

The way I debug it is to have `dotenv.config({path: dotenvPath, debug: true});` in my code and then when I run `set NODE_ENV=development &  node index.js` in CMD, I get

```
development 
.env.development 
[dotenv][DEBUG] Failed to load .env.development  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.env.development '
undefined
development
```

I notice the space in the file name, which leads to the `.env.development`  could not be found.

Then I change the command to `set NODE_ENV=development&node index.js`, then it starts working.

```
development
.env.development
5001
development
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

> set NODE_ENV=production && node index.js

Please use

> set NODE_ENV=production&&node index.js

(without redundant whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can access `process.env` variables **AFTER** `dotenv` package is executed.

So, when you pass a .env variable to it's config, it's still not available for the server.

Comment: Hi @NeNaD, can you please explain a bit more? and do you have any idea how to resolve it? I added some update in my post. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I tried in my local following this post and everything worked as expected.

> [Toggle between multiple .env files like .env.development with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406055/toggle-between-multiple-env-files-like-env-development-with-node-js)

Adding a screenshot for the proof of work
[image: Code With Output]

Comment: Hi @Jagraj Singh, thank you for your example. For some reason, I am still not able to get it working. Please see the updated example in my post.

Comment: For CMD can you try this once? D:\>set NODE_ENV=development &&  node index.js @Ben

Comment: Hi @Jagraj Singh, thank you for you advice. However, I get the same result. I tried to run `set NODE_ENV=development && node index.js` directly in CMD, or create a new script `"start:development:windows": "set NODE_ENV=development && node index.js",` and run `npm run start:development:windows` in Terminal of vscode.

Comment: Thank you @Jagraj Singh, I found the reason.