# How can I distinguish between .env.production and .env.statging in node js?

Tags: node.js, express

I want different .env files to be loaded on the production server and on the staging server. What approaches are there for this?

**Note:** Currently i use the `dotenv` package.

Comment: How do you load `.env` files now?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski with the `.dotenv` package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toggle between multiple .env files like .env.development with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406055/toggle-between-multiple-env-files-like-env-development-with-node-js)

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thank you for the useful link. But I don't understand how the application should know that it is on the production server or on the staging or local. If I have three .env files:
`.env.local, .env.production, .env.staging`. I seem to have a problem understanding this.

Comment: You should set `NODE_ENV` variable

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I think now I've realised it. I can only have one .env in the node project. this is not shared in the repository. That means I have to manually put it on the server with the right credentials to stage. Correct? Then I have access to the .env and the set vars.

Comment: You usually don't store environment variables on the servicer inside an `.env` file.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski okay? Where then?