# Deploy Dockerized NodeJS application with the respective .env files

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment, dotenv

I am working on a NodeJS application which is a containerized application. I use Jenkins to build and deploy it. I have an environment `.env` file and along with this, also have `.env` files based on environments.

For example: `.env.DEV`, `.env.SQA`, `.env.STG` and `.env.PROD`.

Each file has different values for the variables based on environments.

[image: Project Structure with all env files]

When I am deploying my application, it always fetches variables from the `.env` file instead of specific environment file i.e. `.env.DEV` (if deploying on DEV server).

How do we use specific environment file while doing the deployment on Jenkins?

Note: I followed this great [content](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786) on `dotenv` library but I didn't find anything helpful for my use-case. I did some research on the web, but didn't find much on this.

Comment: Have you tried to use something like `require('dotenv').config({ path: .env.${ENVIRONMENT_TO_READ}`})` and seting the ENVIRONMENT_TO_READ when running the container

Comment: Are you talking about Docker environment variables or Node environment variables? Are your environment files inside the image or outside?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toggle between multiple .env files like .env.development with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406055/toggle-between-multiple-env-files-like-env-development-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dotenv-flow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-flow) which does exactly this, given the value of NODE_ENV environment value it will load the expected environment.

You also will need to make sure that the container receives the proper environment values from jenkins, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins) might help.

Comment: Can you expand this answer to have enough details on its own to be a complete answer?  As it is right now, it's just a couple of links.

Comment: sure, i'll add more detailed steps as soon as possible