# Set NODE_ENV in package.json

Tags: node.js, express, mern

I'm trying to create different environment (production and development) to make sure the production database is not touched during developing. There were lots of answers from this post [Toggle between multiple .env files like .env.development with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406055/toggle-between-multiple-env-files-like-env-development-with-node-js), and what I have for now is

```
    "start": "export NODE_ENV=development&& nodemon server.js",
    "prod": "export NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon server.js"
```

This method works but I'm not really sure why the OP said "gets messy when using multiple variables", and there are other articles/posts saying that it is not a good practice to do "NODE_ENV=development" in packages.js.

My team is currently developing this website, but there will be another team to deploy it, so I need to make sure that the database and other resources such as API tokens can be switched to the one used in production env by simply running `npm run prod`

So my question is what could be the potential issues of this method? Is there any better way to achieve this? Thanks