# unable to load different .env files according to git branches, NestJs v10

Tags: environment-variables, nestjs, nestjs-config

I'm trying to set different `.env` files for my `dev` and `prod` environment accoridng to my `git branches`, like I want to set `.env.dev` for `dev branch` and `.env.prod` for `main` branch, So whenever I switch between branches I don't have to manually comment or uncomment `envFilePath` in `ConfigModule`.

**But the issue is that the `process.env` isn't working. As i'm not able to connect with my database and face error `Unable to connect to database`**

**Code**

```
import simpleGit from 'simple-git';


@Module({
  imports: [
    setConfigModule(),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      `mongodb://${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}/${process.env.NAME}?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&directConnection=true&ssl=false`,
    ),

  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}

async function setConfigModule() {
  const git = simpleGit();
  const gitBranches = await git.branch();
  const currentBranch: string = gitBranches.current;
  console.log(currentBranch);

  if (currentBranch === 'main') {
    return ConfigFactory.loadProdConfig();
  }

  return ConfigFactory.loadDevConfig();
}

export class ConfigFactory {
  static loadDevConfig() {
    return ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: '.env.dev',
    });
  }

  static loadProdConfig() {
    return ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: '.env.prod',
    });
  }
}
```

**When I do this It works fine**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true, envFilePath: '.env.dev' }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(
      `mongodb://${process.env.HOST}:${process.env.PORT}/${process.env.NAME}?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&directConnection=true&ssl=false`,
    ),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toggle between multiple .env files like .env.development with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55406055/toggle-between-multiple-env-files-like-env-development-with-node-js)

Comment: That answer doesn't belong to my question. There we are depending to `package.json script cli commands`, I'm depending here on the `git`branches

Comment: Am I able to make myself clear?

Comment: As I stated In my question I want to load `.env` , `dynamicaly` whenver I switch between branches, but in the answer you suggested, we have to change `cli commands`, ad that I don't want. As usually we keep our production code in the `main` branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reading from `process.env` you should be using `ConfigService` from `@nestjs/config` via the [`forRootAsync` method on `MongooseModule`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#async-configuration)

Comment: That worked. YOU ARE AWESOME. Also I understand the problem as well,